# Access derived member instead of base member with same name in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns

Assume I have two classes

```
class Base 
{
    private:
    std::vector<int> nums;
public:
    virtual void addNum(int num){
        nums.push_back(num);
    }
 }

class Derived : public Base 
 {
    private:
       std::vector<int> nums;
 }
```

When I use the derived class and trying to push numbers into its own nums vector
it is probably referring to the base vector instead of the derived one.

How can I refer to the nums vector in the derived class from the parent without overriding the function addNum

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to give `Derived` its own `nums` vector but _not_ override `addNum`. The answer to your question might be the curiously recurring template pattern but it's hard to say for sure without knowing what you're actually trying to accomplish with this class design.

Comment: I'm using the observer design pattern and every derive class with is a subject has its own vector of observers, so when i use the addNum I'm actually calling addObserver to the append a new observer, the problem is that i cant tell the program to refer to the derived vector

Comment: You can't do that, C++ simply doesn't work this way on a fundamental level. Only class methods can be virtually overridden, and not class members.

Comment: I think you are mixing up class declarations with class instances. Derived doesn't needs its own set of nums, when you make an instance of a derived class it will also have its own unique instances of the members of the base class.  Try it, make nums virtual in the base class and remove nums from the derived class. Then make an instance of both the Base class and of the Derived class add some obeservers and inspect them in your debbuger. If you add obeservers to the instance of the derived class none will be added to the instance of the base class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using member functions. However, you *can* do that using a generic function (or an *algorithm*). As your members are `private`, you'll need to make the algorithm a friend, though:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T> void print(T const&);
template <typename T> void addNum(T&, int);

class Base 
{
    template <typename T> friend void print(T const&);
    template <typename T> friend void addNum(T&, int);

private:
    std::vector<int> nums;
};

class Derived : public Base 
{
    template <typename T> friend void print(T const&);
    template <typename T> friend void addNum(T&, int);
private:
    std::vector<int> nums;
};


template <typename T>
void print(T const& obj) {
    for (auto x: obj.nums) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

template <typename T>
void addNum(T& obj, int num) {
     obj.nums.push_back(num);
}

int main()
{
    Base b;
    addNum(b, 1);
    addNum(b, 2);
    print(b);

    Derived d;
    addNum(d, 3);
    addNum(d, 4);
    addNum(static_cast<Base&>(d), 5);
    print(static_cast<Base&>(d));
    print(d);
}
```

I don't necessarily think that an approach like that is well-advised. However, it is certainly doable. A variation of a similar idea is to actually access the `nums` container through a `virtual` function, yielding the respective version of the corresponding derived class:

```
class Base 
{   
private:
    std::vector<int> d_nums;
    virtual std::vector<int> &nums() { return this->d_nums; }
public:
    void addNum(int num) { nums().push_back(num); }
};  

class Derived : public Base 
{   
private:
    std::vector<int> nums;
    std::vector<int> &nums() override { return this->d_nums; }
};
```